# Restart a pod on different node from a pod in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, gcloud

I have deployed a spring boot application on a pod(pod1) on a node(node1). I have also deployed JMeter on another pod(pod2) on a different node(node2). I am trying to perform automated load testing from pod2. To perform load testing, I require to restart the pod1 for each test cases. How do I restart pod1 from pod2?

Answer (score 1):

To restart or delete a pod from another pod you have to access the APIServer.
There are many ways to do this check this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod).

You also have to authorize the pod user to do this, build a Role and a Rolebinding entity.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? I am beginner in Kubernetes and I don't really get what is the link you shared

Comment: Authorize  explanation : Apiserver has a way to protect itself from unauthorized users.  
To request anything from Apiserver you have to define a  serviceaccount to identify your pod and assign permisions to your pod service account.  
Role  is created to define a group of permisions to list and delete the pod etc.  
RoleBinding is a way to assign that group of permisions to your serviceAccount, it connect the service account with the role.

Answer (score 1):

**Via kubectl:**

Install kubectl and configure in the pod2 and then do `kubectl delete pod1` via shell after every load-testing

**Via Springboot:**

Add actuator dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Enable shutdown

`management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true`

Request to shutdown

`curl -X POST IP:port/actuator/shutdown`

Comment: I have installed kubectl in the pod. How do I configure?

Comment: The same way that you have done it in your local! by using .kube/config

Comment: I am using google cloud, cloud shell. In cloud shell, kubectl was installed and configured already. Could you share some reference link to configure?

Comment: Install sdk https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstarts and then `gcloud components install kubectl`  authentication : https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login

Comment: I tried the above steps. But it doesn't seem to work. It throws the following error , when I execute `kubectl get pods`. `Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default"`

Comment: The error is caused because your pod automatically get a default service account asigned. 
1 - you have to define your own service account
2 - Assign this service account to your pod.
3 - Define a Role with attributes enough to acomplish the task to delete the pod. 4 - Define a Rolebinding to assign that Role to the service account.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a deployment type workload you can go into in through Workloads > [Deployment name] > Managed Pods [Pod name] and delete the pod.

You can also do this with `kubectl delete pod [pod name]`

If you have a minimum number of pods for that deployment set then GKE will automatically spin up another pod, effectively restarting it.

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/deployment